# How can I set a TextBox text programmatically in XAML (Silverlight)

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a TextBox inside a DataTemplate in my XAML:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="aproved" >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="70" Height="70" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  >
            <Image Source="/PF;component/Images/checked_checked.png" Width="50" Height="50"></Image>
            <TextBlock Name="tbAproved" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Aproved" />               
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

I want to translate the text "Aproved" in my TextBlock using my translator class (LanguageManager), who is responsable to get strings from my resources files:

```
public class LanguageManager {
    public static String GetString(String resourceName) {
        if (Singleton.Instance().IdLanguage == 2) {
            return ResourceEnglish.ResourceManager.GetString(resourceName);
        } else {
            return ResourcePortuguese.ResourceManager.GetString(resourceName);
        }
    }
}
```

So in my textbox I was trying to do something like this:

```
<TextBlock Name="tbAproved" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="LanguageManager.GetString('resourceName')"/>
```

Geting the string direcly from my class and passing a parameter with the resourceName.

I am using Silverlight 4.

Is there any way to do this? I have to do something complety different in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as simple as this:

```
tbApproved.Text = LanguageManager.GetString("resourceName");
```

If you want use Binding in XAML (recommended):

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="aproved" >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="70" Height="70" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  >
        <Image Source="/PF;component/Images/checked_checked.png" Width="50" Height="50"></Image>
        <TextBlock Name="tbAproved" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding ApprovedLabel}" />               
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Set DataContext to View Model that has ApprovedLabel Property:

```
    public string ApprovedLabel
    {
        get {return LanguageManager.GetString("resourceName");}
        set {}
    }
```